# c# asp.net web app sha 256 password verification failure

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, sha256

I have a login form in c# asp.net where I am storing the hashed password of user in database, if I enter same password again, it says login failure.Here 'textbox2' is password field and 'g' is the hashed password.I am passing 'g' through sql command but login always fails. If I pass the password in plain text , the login is successful ,btw I have hardcoded the hash value in my database (visual studio) as varchar(max).Is this a issue? thanks.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string g = TextBox2.Text;

    StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();

    using (SHA256 hash = SHA256Managed.Create())
    {
        Encoding enc = Encoding.UTF8;
        Byte[] result = hash.ComputeHash(enc.GetBytes(g));

        foreach (Byte b in result)
            Sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
    }

    g = Sb.ToString();

    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"connectionstring");

        String query = "select * from admin where Id = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'and secret = '" + g + "'";


        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, con);
       myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", TextBox1.Text);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@secret", g);
        SqlDataReader dbr;
        con.Open();
        dbr = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        int count = 0;
        while (dbr.Read())
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }
        con.Close();
        if (count == 1)
        {
            Response.Redirect(@"main.aspx");               
        }
        else
        {
            Label3.Visible = true;
        }

    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String query = "select * from admin where Id = @Id and secret = '@secret'";
```

And you can find more information about SqlCommand and parameters on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)